# Drupal 7 Boost is creating but not serving cached pages

Tags: drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 site and I installed Boost which I have installed successfully on other sites.  On this specific site, Boost is creating the cached pages but not serving them.  I'm able to navigate to the cached pages using www.mysite.com/cache/normal/mysiteURL/cachedpage.html and the cached page displays correctly.  I thought the problem might have been that the pages were being re-cached with every request but I checked and the cached pages appear to be remaining for the expiration period I've set so they are not being re-cached.

Can anyone suggest why Boost is able to create the cached pages but the system is not serving them?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch off drupals builtin 'cache pages for anonymous users'. And after this you empty cache. Boost will only work for anonymous users, be aware of it.